# Excel VBA to export chart to word with bookmark

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have created a macro that exports multiple charts from excel to word. However I want to place those chart in some BOOKMARK to fix their position. Can i get some help.

```
Sub ExportingToWord_MultipleCharts_Worksheet()

    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim SecCnt As Integer

    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim ChrtObj As ChartObject
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    
    'Create a new instance of Word
    Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\md.docx")
        'WrdApp.Visible = True
           
    'Loop through the charts on the active sheet
    For Each ChrtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    
        'Copy the chart
        ChrtObj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

        'Paste the Chart in the Word Document
        With WrdApp.Selection
            .PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine
        End With
        
        'Count the pages in the Word Document
        SecCnt = WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
        
        'Add a new page to the document.
         WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add

        'Go to the newly created page.
        WrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
        
    Next ChrtObj

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to use a bookmark?  It's a pretty small edit - bookmarks are accessed by name, and have a `Range` property you can paste to...

Comment: I am not sure how to use them, can you please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606456/pasting-a-table-into-open-word-document-at-a-bookmark

Comment: I guess this would insert only one chart but i need to insert multiple charts in multiple bookmark. Is there a way out?

Comment: Use a loop (you already have one...)?  Write that line multiple times?